# Get a reference to the Api that triggers an AWS::Serverless::Function in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In a CloudFormation template, I'm defining a serverless application with a lambda function triggered by an API gateway, as follows:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      # ...
      Events:
        GetStuff:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /stuff
            Method: get
```

This generates an API Gateway resource that is set up to recieve `GET` requests and forward to my lambda, and it works just as I want it.

However, I can't figure out how to reference that API instance in the `Output` section of the template:

```
Output:
  MyGatewayId:
    Description: Id of the auto-generated API Gateway resource
    Value: # what do I put here?
```

I've tried `!GetAtt MyFunction.RootResourceId` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42249358/38055), but that resulted in a failure when I tried to deploy the stack:

> Failed to create the changeset: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state Status: FAILED. Reason: Invalid template resource property 'MyGatewayId'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to be able to output The key to this is understanding what the Serverless transform is doing for you, generating a series of resources based on your specification.

You can check your CloudFormations resources to be sure, but based on your spec

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      # ...
      Events:
        GetStuff:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /stuff
            Method: get
```

It should generate you a few resources. Based on your `Events` property, and the fact that you did not specify a [RestApiId](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api), it will generate a default API Gateway Rest API for you, and give it the Logical id of `ServerlessRestApi`. So to answer your original question regarding `Outputs`

```
Output:
  MyGatewayId:
    Description: Id of the auto-generated API Gateway resource
    Value: !Ref ServerlessRestApi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have it as an output, if you specify the API gateway in your template.

```
Resources:
  MyAPI
    Type AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      DefinitionUri: s3://<bucket>/swagger.yaml
```

With this approach you have a resource that you can use in your outputs. However, this also requires that you use swagger since the `DefinitionUri` is a required attribute.

You can always extract the id with the following command:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources --stack-name <your-stack> \
    --query "StackResources[?ResourceType == 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'].PhysicalResourceId" \
    --output text
```

Which means that you can also easily extract the url to your API by:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources --stack-name <your-stack> \
    --query "StackResources[?ResourceType == 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'].PhysicalResourceId" \
    --output text \
    | awk '{print "https://"$1".execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Prod"}'
```

Comment: Since my end goal was to get the deploy script to output these parameters, a couple of extra CLI calls is perfectly fine. Thanks!