# How do you get the API endpoint's URL when it's created within the Events property of Cloudformation's Lambda definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless, aws-sam, aws-api-gateway

I'm creating a Lambda function via CloudFormation (AWS' SAM: Serverless Application Model) and have defined an API endpoint via the Lambda-function's Events property.

```
  ...
  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Description: Do amazing things
      CodeUri: my_function/
      Events:
        Trigger:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /p1/{v1}
            Method: post
      Handler: app.run
  ...
```

I'd now like to use the URL of the endpoint that's been created in another part of the CloudFormation YAML file. I've tried to use [the SAM documentation for Lambda](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction) but the only return values have to do with the Function's ARN and resource name.

Specifically, thought I think unrelated to the exact question, I want to use the API endpoint as a subscription for an SNS Topic.

**¿How can I get the URL of the API Endpoint?**

Comment: Can you provide an example of an endpoint URL that corresponds to the resource being created?

Comment: This would end up being [the template for] the URL endpoint generated by the above: https://{{uuid}}.execute-api.{{aws-region}}.amazonaws.com/Prod/p1/v1=abc

Comment: Got it. I have used the Fn:Join function to generate various Urls that are not directly returned by a resource or by Fn:GetAtt. Do you have a way to get the uuid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer across a couple of places.

[This Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46091527/get-a-reference-to-the-api-that-triggers-an-awsserverlessfunction-in-cloudfo) shows that there is an implicit reference created that you can use as follows

`!Ref ServerlessRestApi`

This was supported in practice, by a [SAM Respository App](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home?region=us-west-2#/create/app?applicationId=arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:903779448426:applications/sns2chime)

And then I re-read, more closely, the [SAM API documentation](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api) which shows the `RestApiId` Property. It says

> ...Typically, this is set to reference an AWS::Serverless::Api resource defined in this template. If not defined, a default AWS::Serverless::Api resource is created..."

So it looks like you can reference it as `!Ref ServerlessRestApi` without any modification to the YAML in the original question, or you could add the following Property, `RestApiId: MyAPI`, and reference it as `!Ref MyAPI`.

However, to get the actual URL, it looks like you have to use a Fn::Sub to glue together a couple of parts. Pahud Hsieh does it in his SAM Repository app above

```
Outputs:
  APIUrlPrefix:
    Value:
      Fn::Sub:
      - https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/incomingwebhooks/
      - Region:
          Ref: AWS::Region
        ServerlessRestApi:
          Ref: ServerlessRestApi
...
```

Comment: You have a trailing ' too much in the URL. Otherwise it works perfectly! Was just looking around for this answer yesterday, so thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

you can directly reference the `RestApi` resource like this.

```
Resources:
  apiGateway:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-my-api
      Description: my-api-edge


Outputs:
  apiGatewayInvokeURL:
    Value: !Sub "https://${apiGateway}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${apiGatewayStageName}"

  lambdaArn:
    Value: !GetAtt "lambdaFunction.Arn"
```